# org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

I'm unable to find the solution. Why I'm getting this `[QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-NON_CLUSTERED_MisfireHandler] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.` For a tempory fix, I'm restarting the server and regenerating the job. now don't want to restart the server if the bill generations failed. I need a permanent solution to this.not sure how to resolve it.

1. My scheduler for creating and executing the job.

   ` @Service
   public class HScheduler {

   public static final String DATA = "jobData";

   public static final String BEAN_NAME = "beanName";

   public static final String OPERATION_TYPE = "operation";`

   @Autowired
   private Scheduler scheduler;

   @Autowired
   private INextKeyService nextKeyService;

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HScheduler.class);

   public void createNewJob(Object data, String uniqueRefId, String entityType, SchedulerOperation operation, String beanName, Date scheduleDate) {

   ```
   try {

       String nextKey = nextKeyService.getNextKey("hdatabase", "scheduler", "jobCount");

       String jobName = uniqueRefId + "-" + entityType + "-" + operation.name() + "-" + nextKey;
       scheduleDate = DateUtils.truncate(scheduleDate, Calendar.DATE);

       JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SchedulerJobExecutor.class).withIdentity(jobName).build();
       SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(jobName).startAt(new Date(scheduleDate.getTime() + 5000)).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()).build();
       simpleTrigger.getJobDataMap().put(DATA, GsonUtils.getJsonStringFromObject(data));
       simpleTrigger.getJobDataMap().put(OPERATION_TYPE, operation.name());
       simpleTrigger.getJobDataMap().put(BEAN_NAME, beanName);
       scheduler.isStarted();
       scheduler.scheduleJob(job, simpleTrigger);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error(e.toString(), e);
       throw new HRCSchedulerException("Can't able to Schedule job for Id : " + uniqueRefId + " and Entity Type : " + entityType);
   }
   ```

   }
   }`

It is executed when the triggered is called.

`   @Override
    @Transactional(timeout = 900)
    public void executeJob(String data, SchedulerOperation operation) {

```
    String actionToBePerformed = null;

    if (operation.name().contains("FAILED")) {

        Bill bill = billRepo.findOne(new Long(data));

        if (bill == null) {
            // If it comes here, there is no bill entry at all. So no worries.
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Bill not found with ID : " + new Long(data));
        }

        if (SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION_FAILED.name().equals(operation.name())) {
            actionToBePerformed = "Bill Generation Failed";
        } else {
            actionToBePerformed = "Bill Regeneration Failed";
        }


    } else {

        try {

            Bill oBill = populateSupplementSummaries(new Long(data));

            if (SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION.name().equals(operation.name())) {
                actionToBePerformed = "Bill Generated";
            } else {
                actionToBePerformed = "Bill Regenerated";
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            oBill ownerBill = ownerBillRepo.findOne(new Long(data));

            if (ownerBill == null) {
                // If it comes here, there is no bill entry at all. So no worries.
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Feed Supl. Owner Bill not found with ID : " + new Long(data));
            }

            SchedulerOperation toBePerformedOperation = null;

            if (SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION.name().equals(operation.name())) {
                toBePerformedOperation = SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION_FAILED;
            } else {
                toBePerformedOperation = SchedulerOperation.BILL_REGENERATION_FAILED;
            }

            // Will execute after one minute
            Date scheduleDate = new Date(new Date().getTime());

            scheduler.createNewJob(billId, billId.toString(), Bill.ENTITY_TYPE, SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION, "BillService", scheduleDate);
            throw new ApplicationException(e);
        }
    }
}`
```

Peace of line to call the trigger Or creating the job.

`Date scheduleDate = new Date(new Date().getTime());
  scheduler.createNewJob(billId, billId.toString(), Bill.ENTITY_TYPE, SchedulerOperation.BILL_GENERATION, "BillService", scheduleDate);`

Comment: misfire can to tricky: which value for misfire threshold ? are you sure that you Service is timeouted (not only by @transactional) ?

Comment: Yes @Eric , if i run one job and wait until it complete no issue. If I run multiple jobs one after one then I’m getting that missed their scheduled fire-time